# how to add numbering to each sentence using python or pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this.

| data |
| --- |
| '(p) apple (/p) (p) boy (/p) (p) cat (/p)' |
| ------------------------------------- |
| '(p) apple (p) (p) boy (/p)' |

and I want something like this:

| data |
| --- |
| '(p) 1.apple (/p) (p) 2.boy (/p) (p) 3.cat (/p)' |
| ------------------------------------------- |
| '(p) 1.apple (p) (p) 2.boy (/p)' |

I want to add numbering for every '(p)' tag for every row. A row can contain any number of

tags, so I want to add according to that.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Hint: `df['data'].str.replace` accept regex patterns. You can extract the pattern, add the enumeration, then add the `(p)` back. Please show some of your effort in the question.

Comment: sorry, i am not good with regex. can u please help me with that. Do i neeed to count the number of 'p' tags first for enumeration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would match a regular expression pattern and then rebuild the `(p)...(/p)` element:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# Test DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":["(p)apple(/p)(p)boy(/p)(p)cat(/p)","(p)apple(/p)(p)boy(/p)"]})

pattern = re.compile("\(p\)(.*?)\(/p\)")

df["data"].apply(lambda x: [f'(p){i+1} {s}(/p)' for i, s in enumerate(pattern.findall(x))])
```

Comment: Thank You So Much for this answer. It worked for me.